# What is the difference between "particularly" and "in particular"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Is there any difference between *particularly* and *in particular*?

When should I use each one of them?

Comment: I'd say they're more or less equivalent; all the sentences I'm thinking of work with either "particularly" and "in particular"... though it'd be "...speaking in particular...", but "...particularly speaking..."

Answer (score 15):

"In particular" can be used as a sentential adverb, in the same way that "yesterday" can be.

*Particularly* can usually be used as a sentential adverb (but "in particular" often sounds better in these situations):

- In particular, I eat bread at lunch and dinner.
- Particularly, I eat bread at lunch and dinner.  (Works, but "in particular" sounds a bit better)

On the other hand, *particularly* is used to modify an adjective (or adverb) directly, and "in particular" cannot do this.  Compare:

- I did particularly well on that exam.  (Modifying an adjective, "well")
- *I did in particular well on that exam. (Ungrammatical)

Comment: Ah yes, for the service of modifying an adjective or adverb, it sounds off. You'd also sometimes hear "I, in particular, ..."

Comment: Or at the end: "I eat bread at lunch and dinner in particular."  These are all the sentential uses I am talking about (I feel like there is a better word than "sentential", but in any case, not directly modifying an adjective or adverb).